# UK Standard visitor visa for multiple business trips

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel

I have a question regarding visiting the UK on multiple occasions for business. I am living in another European country with a permanent residence permit there. The visits to the UK would last 2-3 weeks, then 1-2 weeks home, 2-3 weeks UK and so forth, given a standard visitor visa is present. Would the IO be suspicious about the frequent visits? It is not work, but business in a consulting/training area which requires frequent presence in the UK at our business partners location. I do not directly do business with clients of our partner. I am paid by my employer in the home country and I do not intend to migrate to the UK. Would these type of visits require another visa and which one would you recommend? I do not want to cause distress of removal on the UK border and cause a permanent rejection for future visits to the UK. So it is important to find a legal way for frequent visits in a time period of approx, one year (I would have to apply for a new visa after the current one has expired).

Comment: It's tricky since you would end up spending a majority of your time in the UK on that pattern. Also, the business visitor is only allowed to brief or be briefed so that the main work can be carried out in your home country. You describe something that looks very much like working in the UK despite you saying that it is consulting and training: both of those are forms of work. Your firm should employ a lawyer to answer this definitely since there is a business risk if you get shut out in the middle of a project.

Comment: Are you giving the training or receiving it? And can you give more details about what you mean by 'consulting'?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions, putting on hold.